# Type Error: How do I get a method to execute like a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to create a Javascript function in HTML,which should create a rectangle and set the size to the likings of the user with this code:

```
class Rectangle{
  constructor(height, width){
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;

  function createRectangle(Rectangle){
    var input1 = document.getElementbyId("1stinput").value;
    var input2 = document.getElementbyId("#2ndinput").value;
    var input1int = parseFloat(input1);
    var input2int = parseFloat(input2);
    var Rectangle1 = new Rectangle(this.height=input1int, this.width=input2int);};
    document.querySelector("Rectangle").setAttribute('width', parseFloat(Rectangle1.width));
    document.querySelector("Rectangle").setAttribute('height', parseFloat(Rectangle1.height));
};
};
</script>
<input type="text" name="" value="" id="1stinput">
<input type="text" name="" value="" id="2ndinput">
<button onclick=Rectangle.createRectangle(Rectangle)>create</button>
<svg width=0 height=0>
  <rect width=0 height=0 style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" id="Rectangle"/>
</svg>
```

But that didn't work,I got this Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Rectangle.createRectangle is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

So I think,that createRectangle shoud be a method,but I don't know how to implement methods in the button,can someone Please help me?
That would be very nice,thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to revisit how you're approaching this. Classes have methods so you can't just add a function to them ([here's the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)). Additionally, maybe keep DOM manipulations out the class itself, and just let that return an HTML string based on the input values. You can then add that to a DOM element of your choosing.

```js
class Rectangle {
  
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  createRectangle() {
    return `
      <svg>
        <rect width="${this.width}px" height="${this.height}px"></rect>
      </svg>
    `;
  }

}

const input1 = document.querySelector('#input1');
const input2 = document.querySelector('#input2');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const output = document.querySelector('#output');

button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick() {
  const n1 = parseFloat(input1.value);
  const n2 = parseFloat(input2.value);
  const rectangle = new Rectangle(n1, n2);
  output.innerHTML = rectangle.createRectangle();
}
```

```css
svg { width: 100%; }
rect { fill: rgb(0, 0, 255); stroke-width: 3; stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);}
#output { margin-top: 1em; }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1">
<input type="text" id="input2">
<button>create</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Great,the code works fantastic,Thanks for helping me,now I only have to fugure out how it works,thanks for helping me!

Comment: Take a look at the additional documentation at the end of the post that will explain how `querySelector` and template strings work. Basically I cached all the relevant elements outside of the class, and had the class return an HTML string when the `createRectangle` method was called. That gets applied to the output element.